# Localization at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I have created Windows Form Program in C#.
I have some problems with localization.
I have resource files in 3 languages.
I want to click each language button and change language at runtime.
When i am changing language before `InitializeComponent()` it works.
But when i am clicking on button, it doesn't work.
i am using this code.

```
private void RussianFlag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried also change `Thread.CurrentCulture` as well?

Comment: Have you tried calling a `Refresh()` after you set the thread culture to another language?

Comment: I doubt you would need a `ComponentResourceManager` and apply maybe by looping though all the controls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to reload the controls for it to reflect the New culture values

```
ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
```

and then you would have to apply for each control using `resources.ApplyResources`

Please have a [look here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=174)

Comment: Although a good introduction tutorial, it opens the door to several problems

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a `RuntimeLocalizer` class with following features:

- Changes and updates localization for all `Control`s and `SubControl`s in a Form
- Also changes localization for all `SubItem`s of all `MenuStrip`s

Usage Example: `RuntimeLocalizer.ChangeCulture(MainForm, "en-US");`

---

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

---

```
public static class RuntimeLocalizer
{
    public static void ChangeCulture(Form frm, string cultureCode)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureCode);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());

        ApplyResourceToControl(resources, frm, culture);
        resources.ApplyResources(frm, "$this", culture);
    }

    private static void ApplyResourceToControl(ComponentResourceManager res, Control control, CultureInfo lang)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(MenuStrip))  // See if this is a menuStrip
        {
            MenuStrip strip = (MenuStrip)control;

            ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(strip.Items, res, lang);
        }

        foreach (Control c in control.Controls) // Apply to all sub-controls
        {
            ApplyResourceToControl(res, c, lang);
            res.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, lang);
        }

        // Apply to self
        res.ApplyResources(control, control.Name, lang);
    }

    private static void ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(ToolStripItemCollection col, ComponentResourceManager res, CultureInfo lang)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)     // Apply to all sub items
        {
            ToolStripItem item = (ToolStripMenuItem)col[i];

            if (item.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripMenuItem))
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem menuitem = (ToolStripMenuItem)item;
                ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(menuitem.DropDownItems, res, lang);
            }

            res.ApplyResources(item, item.Name, lang);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you! The best solution for runtime localization change and very easy to implement!

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you! I have tried many approach and only your works thanks!

Comment: I use this class too. One interesting thing is that it may change size of controls, because dimensions are "localizable" too and their values are stored in resource files. If a form gets "jumpy" after applying this class then remove undesired dimension values from file.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the CurrentUICulture will not automatically reload the resources. You need to perform it manually (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx#S8)

You can copy the code related to the localization from InitializeComponent()
into another function:

```
void LoadResources(){

    this.Title = MyApp.Resources.MainFormCaption;
    this.lblWelcomeMessage.Text = MyApp.Resources.UserWelcome;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks V4Vendetta and others..
Solution is...

```
private void RussianFlag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentLanguage != "RUS")
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
                ChangeLanguage("ru-RU");
            }
        }
```

....
....
...

```
private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
                resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
                if (c.ToString().StartsWith("System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox"))
                {
                    foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
                    {
                        ComponentResourceManager resources_child = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
                        resources_child.ApplyResources(child, child.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here is a recursive solution:           private void ChangeLanguage(Control ctl,  string lang)
        {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            resources.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)  ChangeLanguage(c, lang);
         }