# Localizing a user control with inheritance at runtime VB.net

Tags: vb.net, localization

I have a UserControl which Inherits Listiview and I am tying to figure out how to localize the column headers.

I have looked at [Localization at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980888/localization-at-runtime), but it's not getting me where I need to go.

I create my inherited listviews at runtime, so I somewhow need to iterate the column collection and apply the appropriate localization.

Prior to the Form Intialize, I use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(sLang) and this works successfully on all the form's static controls in changing all the text, but not on my dynamically added listviews' columns.

???

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't the linked answer work? And are you specifically changing culture during runtime?

Comment: The issue is how to set the text values through code - since there is no localized Form resource created for the Inherited control, I see no way to set the column header values to another language.

If the Listview is ALREADY on a FORM (not added dynamically,) then the localization works properly. But that's because the properties for the column headers are available from the designer.

???